# Mysql update trigger change value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with a couple of columns;

datetime_end,
datetime_start,
duration

When the light is switched on, the row is inserted and only datetime_start is filled. When the light is switched off the datetime_end and duration are filled. 
I want a trigger that changes the duration with 40 seconds (duration=duration-40) once the datetime_end is written.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_light_test

BEFORE UPDATE ON light_test
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.duration > 50 THEN
        SET NEW.duration = OLD.duration - 45;
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger is created just fine but doesn't do anything.. even if the light is on for 70 secs.. any ideas?

Comment: for debugging can you insert data into a temp table

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. you mean you want to see actual data?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that before this `UPDATE` is executed, `duration` is null?

Comment: Yes correct, duration and datetime_end are filled after the update

Answer (score 0):

`OLD` contains the record from the table ***before the `UPDATE` is issued.*** In this case, that's `NULL`, so you're always comparing `NULL > 50` which always evaluates to `FALSE`. You want to be comparing to the value in `NEW`, which is the value of the record ***as it will be,*** and which is the value you manipulate in the trigger.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_light_test
  BEFORE UPDATE ON light_test
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.duration > 50 THEN
        SET NEW.duration = NEW.duration - 45;
    END IF;
  END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still get this data in my database; 2016-01-10 19:12:50 (end)   2016-01-10 19:11:45 (start)    65 (duration). Duration should have been 65-45=20 now.

Comment: Show me your `UPDATE` statement. Also, what is the datatype of the column `duration`?

Comment: Duration is datatype INT.. this is the update statement; update light_test set datetime = '2016-01-16 06:42:16', duration = '11424967224'/1000000000 where datetime is null;

Comment: What is `'11424967224'/1000000000`? Where do these numbers come from? I'm wondering why you aren't using something like `duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, datetime_start, datetime_end)`

Comment: That's the duration.. I know the formula you mentioned, but duration isn't always equal to timestampdiff start-end.. thats why I need the trigger to correct it..

Answer (score -2):

Long time I used trigger but, if I understood your question correctly, you want the trigger to run **after** the update.
Wouldn't it be :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_light_test

AFTER UPDATE ON light_test
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.duration > 50 THEN
        SET NEW.duration = OLD.duration - 45;
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried this already before.. it gives me: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger